# Store variables on WebService

Tags: web-services, variables

I remember coming across the web site service that allowed you to store variables with them, through XML/JSON communication.

Simple Key/Value storage.

It was a free service.

I now happen to need it and I cannot dig it up.

Can you suggest any such service?

**~Update**: Found this Amazon SimpleDB, but I need a free service to store Key/Value pairs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I found it, [OpenKeyval](http://openkeyval.org/)

Description: "OpenKeyval is a completely open key-value data store, exposed as a drop-dead simple web service. The goal is to make this a very easy way to persist data in web applications."

Comment: This service does not exist anymore. Could you provide an alternative?